# Prevent Vim from remembering a change

Tags: vim

I like the `'.` command in vim.  From `:help '.`:

```
'.   `.
```

> [Jump to] the position where the last change was made.  The position is at or near where the change started.

Ok.  But here's my problem: I use an `autocmd` function to add a "last modified" line in my file header.  So, after every write, `'.` brings me not to my "real" last change, but to my file header.  My current solution is I try to remember to mark my current editing point with `ma`, so I can `'a` to return to it.  I sometimes forget, though, and even when I remember, it's another couple keystrokes.

My ideal solution would be some sort of command that tells vim not to remember movements.  I could send this command before the `autocmd` function jumps around, writing the last modified line, and then cancel it after the `autocmd` function has finished.  That way, the location associated with `'.` would not be changed.  However, I'm open to any other options that are more efficient.

In case you want to see it, here's what the `autocmd` does on `:w`.

```
function! UpdateHeader()
    let b:winview = winsaveview()

    " This is where I'd put the command to ignore future movements

    "The periods concatenate all the arguments into one command.
    "Silent! suppresses errors, usually 'pattern not found'
    "The 1,6g means search only lines 1 thru 6
    "Search for File Name: followed by anything
    "'s'ubstitute
    "Substitute in 'File Name: ' and the results of the expand command, on the
    "current filename
    execute "silent! 1," . 6 . "g/File Name:.*/s//File Name: " . expand("%")
    execute "silent! 1," . 6 . "g/Last Modified:.*/s//Last Modified: " . strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    " This is where I'd put the command to start remembering movements again

    call winrestview(b:winview)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `:keepjumps {command}` in your `autocmd`.

See `:help :keepjumps`.

Comment: A note for anyone trying to implement this solution: the `keepjumps` command is needed where the *actual modification of the text happens* – namely, in the `:s` command run by the `:g` command: `execute "silent! 1," . 6 . "g/File Name:.*/keepjumps s//File Name: " . expand("%")`.

Comment: One more note: the command as written in the previous comment does prevent `'.` from being set.  However, it still adds to the jumplist.  To prevent *that*, add `keepjumps` again, just after `silent!`.

Comment: The `keepjumps` command must be added before every command for it to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try `:lockmarks <command>` in your `autocmd`. The help for this says that `'.` is one of the things will not be changed by the command.

Comment: I chose the answer citing `:keepjumps` over `:lockmarks` because that command seemed more limited in scope while still fulfilling the stated objective.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @Riley That makes sense. Thanks for asking the question; I learnt a few things.

Answer (score 1):

There might be prettier ways to do this, but how about simply preserving the location in another mark?  Eg:

```
" This is where I'd put the command to ignore future movements
" go to the mark and label it as z
`.mz

" This is where I'd put the command to start remembering movements again
" return to your mark and create a fake edit there to reset the most recent edit mark
`zi <Esc>x
```

Comment: Interesting.  I considered this sort of solution, too.  In fact, the marking wouldn't even be necessary, since the `winsaveview()` and later the `winrestview()` preserve and restore the cursor position.  The more salient point is the "fake" edit, to force the `.` mark back to the right place.  That should work, but, for now, I'm going to hold out for a more "pretty" solution.  If none appears, you get the check.  +1 regardless.